# Tub drains slowly unless I hold down the lever

Tags: drain, bathtub

When I put the tub drain lever in the down position, the water drains from the tub but slowly. If I press and hold down on the lever then it drains at regular speed, can this be fixed or does it need to be totally replaced?

Comment: When was the last time you took it out for cleaning? 

Never?

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning it... It probably won't be pretty. Standard tub stoppers collect hair and get rather vile.

Pushing down on the lever is raising the stopper higher, giving more space around the hair clog, most likely.

If by some bizarre chance your's is already perfectly clean, the rod can be shortened to raise the stopper higher so long as it's not shortened so much that it no longer stops. But usually it's a hair clog,

Comment: Could also be that the mechanism has gotten corroded or has some calcification, so that it doesn't "go all the way" without intervention.

Comment: @Huesmann Should still fall under "cleaning"....

Answer (score 0):

Is the plug adjustable?

Sure, it probably needs cleaning to help the flow-rate, but it could possibly also be adjusted to not give enough clearance. If it's a wire-driven mechanism it could have moved over time [sounds odd, but mine did].

To clean, lift out the plug, pull as as much yucky drain hair as you can, then add a bottle of supermarket drain cleaner & leave overnight.

If it's adjustable, two spanners [wrenches] or screwdriver/spanner will usually do it… might need a squirt of de-scaler to free it up [as this one would].

[image]